# How does one connect to a schema within a PDB (other than schema SYS)?

Tags: oracle-18c

Using Oracle 18c on RedHat Linux 8

Connecting to CDB as 'SYS', I cannot figure out how to connect to a schema within the PDB other than as 'SYS'.  Maybe I don't understand the CDB/PDB architecture well enough.

Here is what I have tried after logging into the Oracle 18c CDB as 'SYS' (using `sqlplus sys as sysdba`):

```
ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER= PDB;
conn myschema/mypasswd
```

and I also tried (right from the CDB)

```
conn myschema/mypasswd@PDB;
```

Both approaches fail to get me connected to the schema `myschema` in the PDB.  That is, I am still 'SYS' in the PDB.

Are there any suggestions/explanations on how to resolve this?
Do I have to setup some kind of access from the CDB-to-PDB for the schema `myschema`?

Comment: `conn myschema/mypasswd@PDB` is the correct method given the `PDB` TNS alias is correct and uses the service for the PDB. I find it difficult to believe you ended up as `SYS` after using this.

Comment: @BalazsPapp Thx.  I ended up as `SYS` because I never got into the schema `myschema` - it failed.  In other words, I remained as `SYS`, which is where I started from.  But I think your point is accurate -- I think there may be an issue with the TNS alias.

Comment: @BalazsPapp You were correct.  Turns out there was a typo in the tnsnames.ora file, IP address field.  The file was probably copied from another server (as a template maybe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a typo error in the `tnsnames.ora` file - the `HOST` ip address field was invalid for the system in question. 
Example below (*values have been anonymized for security reasons*)

```
PDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.10.1.11)(PORT = 1555))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = PDB)
    )
  )
```

The file was probably copied from another server (as a template) and the `HOST` ip never updated.

Given the above, the correct way to connect would be:

```
conn myschema/mypasswd@PDB;
```